# Python - Print successfully if the def has no except errors

Tags: python, python-3.x, ftp

I have this code that send files to a ftp server using try and except.

```
def sendFiles():
    #send a PDF
    try:
        ftp.cwd('/pdf') 
        pdf = "file1.pdf"  # send the file
        with open(pdf, "rb") as file: 
            ftp.storbinary(f"STOR {pdf}", file)  
    except:
        print(colored(255, 0, 0, f"ERROR !!!!!!!! {pdf} was not sent!"))

    #send new POPUP IMAGE
    try:
        ftp.cwd('/image/popup')
        popup = "popup1.jpg" # send the file
        with open(popup, "rb") as file: 
            ftp.storbinary(f"STOR {popup}", file)
    except:
        print(colored(255, 0, 0, f"ERRO !!!!!!!! {popup} was not sent!"))
```

I need: if there's no except errors, i got a print "Files sent with success!"

I tryed this at the end but without success. It is always showing me "Files was not sent!, even i dont get a except error:

```
if sendFiles():
    print("\nFiles sent with success!")
else:
    print("\nFiles was not sent!")
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not returning any value from `sendFiles` so that defaults to a value of `None` which is the same as `False` in an `if` expression. Change `sendFiles` to return a boolean dependent on whether you succeed or not. For example:

```py
def sendFiles() -> bool:
    sentOK = True
    #send a PDF
    try:
        ftp.cwd('/pdf') 
        pdf = "file1.pdf"  # send the file
        with open(pdf, "rb") as file: 
            ftp.storbinary(f"STOR {pdf}", file)  
    except:
        print(colored(255, 0, 0, f"ERROR !!!!!!!! {pdf} was not sent!"))
        sentOK = False

    #send new POPUP IMAGE
    try:
        ftp.cwd('/image/popup')
        popup = "popup1.jpg" # send the file
        with open(popup, "rb") as file: 
            ftp.storbinary(f"STOR {popup}", file)
    except:
        print(colored(255, 0, 0, f"ERRO !!!!!!!! {popup} was not sent!"))
        sentOK = False

    return sentOK
```

If you have a lot of these files to send, you might find a helper function useful. For example:

```py
def sendFile(filename, dirname):
    try:
        ftp.cwd(dirname) 
        with open(filename, "rb") as file: 
            ftp.storbinary(f"STOR {filename}", file)  
    except:
        print(colored(255, 0, 0, f"ERROR !!!!!!!! {filename} was not sent!"))
        return False
    return True
```

Then `sendFiles` simplifies to:

```
def sendFiles():
    sentOK = True
    sentOK = sentOK and sendFile('file1.pdf', '/pdf')
    sentOK = sentOK and sendFile('popup1.jpg', '/image/popup')
    return sentOK
```

There is scope for even more simplification there, for example by passing a list of tuples

```
[('file1.pdf', '/pdf'), ('popup1.jpg', '/image/popup')]
```

to `sendFiles` and then just iterating through the list e.g.

```
def sendFiles(fileList):
    return all(sendFile(file[0], file[1]) for file in fileList)
```

Comment: nice! so i always need to put a False in excepts? if a have 40+ excepts?

Comment: Yes @LucasFernandes, you have, otherwise there may be a single except branch reached without returning False at the end.

Comment: @LucasFernandes yes,  you would need to put a `False` in each except, because any one of them might fail and if you don't have `False` in each one you would miss it

Comment: @LucasFernandes please see my edit; it gives some examples of how you could simplify the code to remove the need to modify all those `except` blocks

Comment: wow! that was cool! it will make my code so much better @Nick thank you very much!!

Answer (score 2):

```
if sendFiles():
```

So you are getting the `bool` value of a function returning `None`, right?

```
if sendFiles():
    print("\nFiles sent with success!")
else:
    print("\nFiles was not sent!")
```

This will always take you to the `else` branch, since `if` "evaluates" `None` as `False`.

---

> *I need: if there's no except errors, i got a print "Files sent with success!"*

You can try a `return` approach...

```
def sendFiles() -> bool:
    try:
        ...
    except:
        return False
```

...or a `bool` approach

```
def sendFiles() -> bool:
    result: bool = True
    try:
        ...
    except:
        result = False
    return result
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using `except Exception as e` to catch the attributes of the exception if it is being triggered, then you can use `e.message` to see if it shows something helpful. Also `if sendFiles(): print("\nFiles sent with success!")` the if statement will always be triggered because it's only condition is that the function is being run, it is not checking wether or not the files were sent.

Maybe you could test it returning a variable.

```
def sendFiles():
    file_sent = False
    image_sent = False
    #send a PDF
    try:
        ftp.cwd('/pdf') 
        pdf = "file1.pdf"  # send the file
        with open(pdf, "rb") as file: 
        ftp.storbinary(f"STOR {pdf}", file)  
        file_sent = True
    except:
        print(colored(255, 0, 0, f"ERROR !!!!!!!! {pdf} was not 
        sent!"))

    #send new POPUP IMAGE
    try:
        ftp.cwd('/image/popup')
        popup = "popup1.jpg" # send the file
        with open(popup, "rb") as file: 
        ftp.storbinary(f"STOR {popup}", file)
        image_sent = True
    except:
        print(colored(255, 0, 0, f"ERRO !!!!!!!! {popup} was not 
        sent!"))
    return file_sent, image_sent

file_sent, image_sent = sendFiles()
        
if all([file_sent, image_sent]):
    print("\nFiles sent with success!")
else:
    print("\nFiles was not sent!")
```